# How to store schema of a nested JSON in a variable in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am able to get the structure of my nested JSON using:
`df.schema`

**I get this:**

```
StructType(StructField(CreatedBy,StringType,true), StructField(Description,StringType,true), StructField(ExpirationDate,LongType,true), StructField(ID,StringType,true), StructField(Name,StringType,true), StructField(Package,StringType,true), StructField(PackageDependencies,StructType(StructField(dataShape,StructType(StructField(fieldDefinitions,StructType(StructField(Name................
```

I want to get only columns with data types. It will be great if someone working on Spark Scala can suggest me this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a sample output how you want for the nested fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for df.dtypes with the help of schema as input.
You can get that using an empty dataframe. Check this out

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val typ = StructType(Seq(
     | StructField("CreatedBy",StringType,true),
     | StructField("Description",StringType,true),
     | StructField("ExpirationDate",LongType,true),
     | StructField("ID",StringType,true),
     | StructField("Name",StringType,true),
     | StructField("Package",StringType,true)));
typ: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(CreatedBy,StringType,true), StructField(Description,StringType,true), StructField(ExpirationDate,LongType,true), StructField(ID,StringType,true), StructField(Name,StringType,true), StructField(Package,StringType,true))

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row],typ)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [CreatedBy: string, Description: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df.dtypes
res8: Array[(String, String)] = Array((CreatedBy,StringType), (Description,StringType), (ExpirationDate,LongType), (ID,StringType), (Name,StringType), (Package,StringType))

scala> df.dtypes.foreach(println)
(CreatedBy,StringType)
(Description,StringType)
(ExpirationDate,LongType)
(ID,StringType)
(Name,StringType)
(Package,StringType)

scala>
```